# Converting Html into PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2013, devexpress

I need to convert html into PDF using **DevExpress 9.2**. html to pdf is not a new thing at all but achieving it in DevEx **9.2** is what I want.

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T298512

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q380381

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T259520

Comment: So given the links posted by @RuchiRahul, Have you tried the solution that DevEx support gave you (Assuming that the Vivek Rawat on the first post is you.)?  If so show what you've got so far ([mcve]), if not, then why not?

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruchi. I got my answer it is not possible to achieve with the version 9.2. The methods to export html to pdf are available in assemblies procided in v11 or higher.